# How to apply class based on positive and negative value using in Angular 4

Tags: angular

I want to change class based on the value in my Angular 4 app.

My Code:

```
<td [ngClass]="{'green': crypto.percent_change_1h < 0, 'red': crypto.percent_change_1h > 0}">
```

It is not working as expected? why

I have gone through many links, I could not find solutions,

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13107

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/9109

[Applying ng-class based on value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23762578/applying-ng-class-based-on-value)

[How to give color to h2 based on positve or negative number angular 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43797908/how-to-give-color-to-h2-based-on-positve-or-negative-number-angular-4) and more.

I know, it can be done using Javascript. It could be better it is possible from Angular itself.

Comment: Second link is from AngularJS.

Comment: Are your classes working? Can you check your developer tools to see if the class is applied?

Comment: no. nothing applied.

Comment: can u pls log value of `crypto.percent_change_1h` and post it ?

Comment: @Dhyey, it is '0.89'. On inspect element `<td style="text-align: left;">0.89%</td>`

Comment: so it's a string not a number, than u would need to parse it to float. You can log `typeof crypto.percent_change_1h` to verfiy if it's a string.